# Finding the Min and Max through Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, superclass

I am having a issues with this problem. For this problem, I am to write a sub-class that interacts with the superclass.

A company has written a large class BankingAccount with many methods including:

Method/Constructor and Description:

- public BankingAccount(Startup s)     constructs a BankingAccount object using information in the Startup object s
- public void debit(Debit d)   records the given debit
- public void credit(Credit c)     records the given credit
- public int getBalance()  returns current balance in pennies

I am to design a new class MinMaxAccount whose instances can be used in place of a BankingAccount object but include new behavior of remembering the minimum and maximum balances ever recorded for the account. You should provide the same methods as the superclass, as well as the following new behavior:

Method/Constructor and Description:

- public MinMaxAccount(Startup s)  constructs a MinMaxAccount object using
- information in the Startup object s
- public int getMin()  returns minimum balance in pennies
- public int getMax()     returns maximum balance in pennies

The account's constructor sets the initial balance based on the Startup information. Assume that only the debit and credit methods change an account's balance.

I am having issues with recording the min and max values, b/c I am not sure if I am on the right track. Currently, it only returns the latest input. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
// This is the subclass
public class MinMaxAccount extends BankingAccount{
private Startup thing;
private int min;
private int max;

    // constructor
    public MinMaxAccount(Startup s) {
        super(s);
        Startup thing = s;
        min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }

    // returns the lowest balance
    public int getMin() { 
        while (super.getBalance()<min) {
            min = super.getBalance();
        }
        return min;
    }

    // returns the highest value
    public int getMax() {
        while (super.getBalance()>max) {
            max = super.getBalance();
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

The superclass provided by Marty Stepp, there is a lot more than that is needed here:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class BankingAccount {
private int balance;

private List<String> historyTransaction;
private List<String> historyBalance;

public BankingAccount() {
    historyTransaction = new LinkedList<String>();
    historyBalance = new LinkedList<String>();
}

public BankingAccount(Startup s) {
    this.balance = s.startup_getBalance();
    historyTransaction = new LinkedList<String>();
    historyBalance = new LinkedList<String>();

    historyTransaction.add(valueToHistory(s.startup_getBalance()));
    historyBalance.add(toString());
}

public void debit(Debit d) {
    balance += d.debit_getBalance();

    historyTransaction.add(valueToHistory(d.debit_getBalance()));
    historyBalance.add(toString());
}

public void credit(Credit c) {
    balance += c.credit_getBalance();

    historyTransaction.add(valueToHistory(c.credit_getBalance()));
    historyBalance.add(toString());
}

public int getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o instanceof BankingAccount) {
        return (this.getBalance() == ((BankingAccount) o).getBalance());
    }
    return false;
}

private String valueToHistory(int value) {
    int absValue = Math.abs(value);
    return (value < 0 ? "(-" : "") + (absValue / 100) + "." + (absValue % 100 / 10) + (absValue % 100 % 10) + (value < 0 ? ")" : " ");
}

public String toString() {
    int absBalance = Math.abs(balance);
    return (balance < 0 ? "-" : "") + "$" + (absBalance / 100) + "." + (absBalance % 100 / 10) + (absBalance % 100 % 10);
}

public String historyBalanceToString() {
    /*int maxLength = 0;
    for(String piece : historyBalance) {
        maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, piece.length());
    }*/
    int maxLength = 8;

    String build = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < historyBalance.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < maxLength - historyBalance.get(i).length(); j++) {
            build += " ";
        }
        build += historyBalance.get(i);
        if(i != historyBalance.size() - 1) {
            build += "\n";
        }
    }

    return build;
}

public String historyTransactionToString() {
    String total = toString() + " ";

    int maxLength = 0;
    for(String piece : historyTransaction) {
        maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, piece.length() + 2);
    }
    maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, total.length() + 2);

    String build = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < historyTransaction.size() - 1; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < maxLength - historyTransaction.get(i).length(); j++) {
            build += " ";
        }
        build += historyTransaction.get(i);
        build += "\n";
    }

    build += "+";
    for(int i = 0; i < maxLength - (historyTransaction.get(historyTransaction.size() - 1).length() + 1); i++) {
        build += " ";
    }
    build += historyTransaction.get(historyTransaction.size() - 1);
    build += "\n";

    for(int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
        build += "-";
    }
    build += "\n";

    for(int i = 0; i < maxLength - total.length(); i++) {
        build += " ";
    }
    build += total;

    return build;
}

public static class Startup {
    private int balance;

    public Startup(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public int startup_getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
}

public static class Debit {
    private int balance;

    public Debit(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public int debit_getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
}

public static class Credit {
    private int balance;

    public Credit(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public int credit_getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
}

//  REPLACEME

}
```

Comment: Using `if` instead of `while` would get you closer to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are missing is that you need to record the min and max when the balance changes, not when it is queried.

Override the methods that change the balance and record the min/max if a new min or max have been set. Return the stored min or max when it is queried.

Comment: If I were to override the methods from the constructor, wouldn't it not fulfill the requirement of only having a constructor and the min/max methods in the subclass?

Comment: @JackL. "You should provide the same methods as the superclass, as well as the following new behavior:" You are providing the same methods as the superclass....